# Any tips for good tutorials or discussions on web page animation?

Tags: website-design, animation

The simple effect I'm ultimately after is this:

- load an image in the centre of a web page
- have the image slide across to the left
- then start loading other text and images around it

I don't mind how many separate web pages are required to do this, or how many separate images, but I'd like to know what my options are. I am more programmer than graphic designer, so maybe I'm searching using the wrong technical terms. Maybe "animation" is too grand a term for so simple an effect, but "slide" has other connotations in this context, and between those two things, I'm struggling to find a clear way to a clear answer. I would ultimately like to understand things like:

- Can the above task be achieved with one image on one page, in HTML, without scripting?
- Does HTML only support "static" elements that appear on screen, and never change their position? If that is the case, does all animation therefore rely on either having (static) elements with dynamic content, or repeatedly loaded/rendered static elements which give an appearance of movement?
- How widespread is browser support for the various animation options?

So as the original question suggests, maybe a tutorial would be good. I haven't found a decent one of those yet either!

Comment: I don't see how this is a graphic design question, when you are looking coding solution ( Well, there is flash.... but... ). I voted to close this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a "pure HTML" solution, you're going to want to look at CSS3 Animations: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp

However, if you're looking for cross-browser compatibility, this is not the way to go. As you can see on that page, IE does not support this yet.

I would use javascript for a more cross-browser friendly solution. A good library to use might be jqueryui: http://jqueryui.com

Comment: IE10 actually does support quite a bit. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673530(v=vs.85).aspx The great thing about CSS animation is that it degrades gracefully and it can be GPU accelerated (unlike jQuery). But I agree if you want to support everything, CSS may not be the best option.

Comment: How many people have javascript disabled as a security risk? Is there a lesser of evils?

Comment: @omatai You could use: css3, jquery ( or some other javascript library ) or flash. All of these have some sort of weakness. **CSS3** = no cross browser support ( and no click functionality, or one that has a good browser support anyways ). **jQuery** ( and js in general ) = This is cross browser method. The percentage of people who have disabled js is quite low, AFAIK. Not to mention you can write js so that if a person does have it disabled, it falls back to simpler interface/functionality. **flash** = quite heavy, good browser support, except some tablets.. namely ios.

Comment: Good example of jquery plugin that has a good solid fallback is Lightbox. Normally, you get a modal window that slides into place and has a nice navigation and so on and so forth... If javascript is disabled, you can still click the image links that open up like any normal html links to image.

Comment: @Joonas What do you mean by "no click functionality"?

Comment: @MarcEdwards I meant a pseudo class that does something when element is clicked. Though I suppose if you are using css3 animations, you might as well use `:target`...

Comment: So... Yea, totally ignore the part about me saying that css3 has no click functionality. :)

Comment: If you're going to go the CSS3 animation route, [Adobe Edge Animate](http://html.adobe.com/edge/animate/) can help you author these animations, and it's free! And it comes with built-in tutorials!

Answer (score 1):

To specifically cover these points:

> Can the above task be achieved with one image on one page, in HTML,
>   without scripting?

You could just about fake it with one great big animated GIF embedded in an HTML page, but it wouldn't be an elegant solution. This really needs scripting and CSS.

> Does HTML only support "static" elements that appear on screen, and never change their position?

Strictly speaking, yes. However an HTML page may also include embedded CSS and Javascript code which may add animation; it would be more common to have the bulk of the CSS and Javscript in separate files.

> If that is the case, does all animation therefore rely on either having (static) elements with dynamic content, or repeatedly loaded/rendered static elements which give an appearance of movement?

More static elements (containing images, blocks of text, or empty to start with) with movement or their content loaded by scripts.

But I would definitely suggest using HTML + CSS to statically position elements first, before looking at any scripting or animation.